# Run python errors.use kereas to implement CNN

Tags: deep-learning

I am learning Deep Learning and want to use python-kereas to implement CNN, but when I run in command, it looks like some errors.

This is my source code. https://github.com/lijhong/CNN-kereas.git

And my fault is like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/CNN-kereas/cnn-kereas.py", line 167, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train,epochs=3)
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 845, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1485, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1140, in _fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2073, in __call__
    feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 982, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[0,868] = 115873 is not in [0, 20001)
         [[Node: embedding_1/Gather = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](embedding_1/embeddi
ngs/read, _recv_embedding_1_input_0)]]
Caused by op u'embedding_1/Gather', defined at:
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/CNN-kereas/cnn-kereas.py", line 122, in <module>
    model_left.add(embedding_layer)
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 422, in add
    layer(x)
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 554, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/embeddings.py", line 119, in call
    out = K.gather(self.embeddings, inputs)
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 966, in gather
    return tf.gather(reference, indices)
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1207, in gather
    validate_indices=validate_indices, name=name)
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/ah0818lijhong/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[0,868] = 115873 is not in [0, 20001)
         [[Node: embedding_1/Gather = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](embedding_1/embeddi
ngs/read, _recv_embedding_1_input_0)]]
```

I hope someone can help me fix it.

Comment: You need to include the code for us to be able to answer. Also do not post errors as images, put them into the question body.

Comment: ok,it's my fault.I will replace it right now.